# Problem with ffmpeg in bash loop

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

When running the following command line to convert multiple .mkv files into .mp4 files, things go awry. It's as if the script tries to run all the commands at once or they get entangled in each other somehow, and the output gets messy. I don't know exactly. When I ran this just now, only the first file was converted. Other times, I seem to get unexpected or random results.

```
ls -1 *.mkv | while read f; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.*}.mp4"; done
```

However, if I do the following, things work as expected:

```
ls -1 *.mkv | while read f; do echo ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -codec copy \"${f%.*}.mp4\"; done > script; bash script
```

But why? What is it with `ffmpeg`? This doesn't happen with bash loops and other commands than `ffmpeg`. I'd like to do it a simple way without escaping quotes, piping to a script file, etc.

Comment: Avoid piping `ls` output, especially to `while read`. Use the `for f in *.mkv; do...` construct.  Oh, and btw, you don't need `-1` when the output is a pipe.

Comment: What don_crissti said. Don't parse `ls` for things like this, especially not media files whose names are very likely to contain strange characters and whitespace. That said, please [edit] your question and show us this messy output you speak of. What does it look like? We can't help unless you show us the actual problem.

Comment: I had this same problem using something like `find . -name "*.aifc" | while read f; do ffmpeg -i $f...` -- ffmpeg was stripping characters off of the input filename and I couldn't figure out why!  Using the `for` construct solved the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`ffmpeg` reads from standard input as well, consuming data meant for `read`. Redirect its input from `/dev/null`:

```
... | while read f; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.*}.mp4" < /dev/null; done
```

That said, don't read the output from `ls` like this. A simple for loop will suffice (and remove the original problem).

```
for f in *.mkv; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.*}.mp4"
done
```

Comment: Will the prior approach work if using `find . -type f` (where `for` won't)?

Comment: It will; just be aware that file names containing newline characters break that approach.

Comment: Filenames containing newline characters; then I'd say the problem would lie elsewhere :)

Comment: No, the problem is with scripts that make naive assumptions about what characters can appear in a file name.

Comment: This was a tough one to debug -- thanks for saving me a headache today!

Comment: An alternative to redirecting stdin with `< /dev/null` is the [-nostdin option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#stdin-option) like in `ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$f" ...`