# Bash - while read line fails when ffmpeg executed in while body

Tags: bash, scripting

I've been scratching my head over this for some time now; maybe one of you can help me.

I am trying to extract video frames from certain positions in a video. For that purpose, the locations are stored in a text file in the format 'hh:mm:ss' with one entry per line. A bash script reads those lines from the file and executes ffmpeg for each line.

The problem is that the input read from the text file changes depending on whether ffmpeg runs 'properly' or not. Without executing ffmpeg, running a different command such as ls, running ffmpeg with invalid settings (so that it immediately exits), everything works as indented. With ffmpeg, the file read from the time stamp file is invalid.

My best guess is that ffmpeg somehow messes with the environment the bash script runs in, however, OS design teaches us that this should be impossible.

Here is a minimal example and its output:

Script `extract.sh`:

```
OUTDIR=samples

for f in test.txt; do    # in reality a proper filter such as "f in video-*.txt"
  BASE=${f%%.txt}
  VIDEO=${BASE}.mkv

  cd $OUTDIR

  while read ss; do
    echo "ffmpeg -i ../${VIDEO} -vsync 0 -ss ${ss} -t 00:00:01 '${BASE}-${ss}-%02d.png'"
    (ffmpeg -i ../invalid.mkv -vsync 0 -ss ${ss} -t 00:00:01 "${BASE}-${ss}-%02d.png" 2>&1) >> ${BASE}.log
    #(ffmpeg -i ../${VIDEO} -vsync 0 -ss ${ss} -t 00:00:01 "${BASE}-${ss}-%02d.png" 2>&1) >> ${BASE}.log
  done < ../${f}

  cd ..
done
```

Timestamp file `test.txt`:

```
00:00:42
00:01:20
00:02:20
00:04:20
00:05:56
00:06:40
```

The first ffmpeg command in the script is an incorrect command (invalid video file). If activated, the input is read correctly from `test.txt`:

```
$ ./extract.sh 
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:00:30-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:00:42 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:00:42-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:01:20 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:01:20-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:02:20 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:02:20-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:04:20 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:04:20-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:05:56 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:05:56-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:06:40 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:06:40-%02d.png'
```

After disabling the first (incorrect) ffmpeg comand and enabling the second (correct) one, the timestamps read from `test.txt` are incorrect:

```
$ ./extract.sh 
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:00:30-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss  -t 00:00:01 'test--%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:01:20 -t 00:00:01 'test-00:01:20-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 05:56 -t 00:00:01 'test-05:56-%02d.png'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please would you `ls -ld samples`. Specifically, is it a symbolic link?

Comment: Nope, it's a regular directory and all permissions are fine:
"drwxr-xr-x 2 someone users         65536 Jul 22 22:53 samples"
The script is run under the owner uid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double-quote your variables when you use them. For example,

   ```
   cd "$OUTDIR"
   ```
2. `ffmpeg` does not like `:` in the output file name. So, strip them from `$ss` (`${ss//:/}`) or change them to something else (`${ss//:/_}`):

   ```
   ffmpeg -i "../$VIDEO" -vsync 0 -ss "$ss" -t 00:00:01 "$BASE-${ss//:/}-%02d.png" >> "$BASE.log" 2>&1 </dev/null
   ```
3. The `../` parent directory construct can break if you're processing across a symbolic link. For that reason it would be better to work into the `samples` directory rather than from it.
4. Generally, try to avoid variable names that are all upper-case. They can conflict with variable names managed by the shell (`$PATH`, `$SECONDS`, etc.)

Putting this all together,

```
#!/bin/bash
outdir=samples

for vt in video-*.txt
do
    base=${vt%.txt}
    video=$base.mkv

    while read ss
    do
        echo "ffmpeg -i '$video' -vsync 0 -ss '$ss' -t 00:00:01 '$outdir/$base-${ss//:/}-%02d.png'" >&2
        ffmpeg -i "$video" -vsync 0 -ss "$ss" -t 00:00:01 "$outdir/$base-${ss//:/}-%02d.png" >> "$outdir/$base.log" 2>&1
    done <"$vt"
done
```

On my own example file this generates 50 PNG files for each sample point.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however, you missed the point: why is it that running ffmpeg changes the behavior of the surrounding bash script? 

To make my point, I applied your suggestions, but bash still fails to read the input properly:

$ ./extract.sh 
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:00:30 -t 00:00:01 'test-000030-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 00:01:20 -t 00:00:01 'test-000120-%02d.png'
ffmpeg -i ../test.mkv -vsync 0 -ss 05:56 -t 00:00:01 'test-0556-%02d.png'

In conclusion, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Very strange. My script worked for me

Comment: Indeed very strange - things like that shouldn't happen. I solved the problem with a Python script for now and may investigate the bash/ffmpeg problem later if I find the time. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe a little late, but the problem with `ffmpeg` is that it reads from standard input as well, consuming data meant for read in the while-read-loop.

I had some strange timestamp messup. To solve this you can redirect standard input in the `ffmpeg` command in two ways:

Option1: put -nostdin right behind ffmpeg in the commandline

Example:

```
while read f; do ffmpeg -nostdin  -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.*}.mp4" ; done
```

Option2: put < /dev/null at the end of the ffmpeg commandline

Example:

```
while read f; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -codec copy "${f%.*}.mp4" < /dev/null; done
```

Found this solution here:

[Problem with ffmpeg in bash loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241535/problem-with-ffmpeg-in-bash-loop)

Comment: Does this really add something not already answered in existing answers to the already answered question? It might be harsh to flag this as low quality, but that's what I'm doing given the no-addition-of-new-info, sloppy inconsistent use of capitals in sentence, non-formatted command examples and examples not being based on original posters commands.